# Access to name of an object in combobox in WPF

Tags: database, wpf, combobox

I have a ComboBox in WPF, and a table (Trainer) in my DataBase. They are linked together as following:

```cs
comboTrain.ItemsSource = (from t in ctx.Trainers select t).ToList<Trainer>();
```

Also, I bind it in xaml as following:

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="comboTrain" ItemsSource="{Binding TrainerCollect}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="TrainerId"/>
```

So, when I run the application, I see the name of all trainers in ComboBox.  Now, I want to show only the name of trainer who is selected in ComboBox.

How can I do that?

Comment: It's hard to understand your purpose. So can you explain clearly what you want?

Comment: @Moha: Did you try `(comboTrain.SelectedItem as Trainer)?.Name` ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my question: with using "comboTrain.Text" I could get the selected item as a string.